# AEC/CBC/PKCS7 java and Web Cryptography API encryption produces two different results

Tags: webcrypto-api

I need to achieve what is done here using java:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;

....


// Generate a random salt
            byte[] salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode("JX5cF0uyCaWdhzw8Y8cHpA==");
            byte[] secret = Base64.getDecoder().decode("FJm8qRF66ST7D/ft2lf7Mxi4Rec4oJr6l8fblM0MTLE=");

            // Create a SecretKeyFactory for PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");

            // Create a KeySpec for PBKDF2
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret).toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);

            // Generate the secret key using PBKDF2
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            // Pad the input data to a multiple of 16 bytes using PKCS7 padding
            int blockSize = 16;
            byte[] dataBytes = dataToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int paddingLength = blockSize - (dataBytes.length % blockSize);
            byte[] paddedData = new byte[dataBytes.length + paddingLength];

            System.arraycopy(dataBytes, 0, paddedData, 0, dataBytes.length);

            for (int i = dataBytes.length; i < paddedData.length; i++) {
                paddedData[i] = (byte) paddingLength;
            }

            // Initialize the cipher for encryption with AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(salt));

            // Encrypt the input text
            byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(paddedData);

            // Encode the result as Base64
            String encryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);

            // Print the encrypted text
            System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + encryptedText);
```

with the Web Cryptography API:

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  let binary = '';

  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const len = bytes.byteLength;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return window.btoa(binary);
}

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  const binaryString = window.atob(base64);

  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}



// Convert the salt, shared key, and text to encrypt to Uint8Array
    const salt = base64ToArrayBuffer("JX5cF0uyCaWdhzw8Y8cHpA==");
    const sharedKeyArray = base64ToArrayBuffer("FJm8qRF66ST7D/ft2lf7Mxi4Rec4oJr6l8fblM0MTLE=");
    const textToEncrypt = "ecrypt-test";

    // Import the shared key as a CryptoKey
    const passwordKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        sharedKeyArray,
        { name: "PBKDF2" },
        false,
        ["deriveKey"]
    );

    // Derive the key using PBKDF2
    const derivedKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: "PBKDF2",
            salt: salt,
            iterations: 65536,
            hash: { name: "SHA-256" }, // Use HMAC-SHA-256
        },
        passwordKey,
        { name: "AES-CBC", length: 256 },
        true,
        ["encrypt"]
    );

    // Pad the input data to a multiple of 16 bytes using PKCS7 padding
    const blockSize = 16;
    const dataBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(textToEncrypt);
    const paddingLength = blockSize - (dataBytes.length % blockSize);
    const paddedData = new Uint8Array(dataBytes.length + paddingLength);

    // Copy the original data bytes
    paddedData.set(dataBytes);

    // Add padding bytes with the padding length
    for (let i = dataBytes.length; i < paddedData.length; i++) {
        paddedData[i] = paddingLength;
    }

    const encryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv: salt,
            length: 256
        },
        derivedKey,
        paddedData
    );

    const encryptedText = arrayBufferToBase64(encryptedData);
    console.log("Encrypted Data (Base64):", encryptedText);
```

However the
the java code produces: **4FzA0ctSthwlCWkOpQFuJqRvm3sj8jHFei+awJ5gYDs=**
the javascript code produces: **I2hnugSw5TwQ7tayAWvaLD808jd1J8L9Bc3EGfD7F9c=**

I need to achieve the same result as in java with the Web Cryptography API

Comment: That's a lot of code to inspect in a post. Please try to pin down the problem better, by logging each intermediate value and result, and it should become clearer where the problem occurs.

Comment: In the Java code, the Base64 encoded string `FJm8....` is *directly* used as password, while in the WebCrypto code this string is *Base64 decoded* before it is applied as password. This is the cause of the issue and must be changed so that it is identical in both codes (e.g. with the following change in the WebCrypto code `const sharedKeyArray = new TextEncoder().encode("FJm8...")`, assuming that the Java code is the reference).

Comment: Also note that the Java Code (and the WebCrypto code) pad twice, once explicitly (see e.g. `arraycopy()`), once implicitly (see e.g. `PKCS7Padding`). This double padding is completely pointless, only increases the amount of data unnecessarily and should be fixed as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that salt (and IV) should be randomly generated for security reasons (there is a note in the Java code to that effect, so the static values are presumably only used for testing purposes).

Comment: @Topaco the change you mentioned was actually the cause of the error.

const sharedKeyArray = new TextEncoder().encode("FJm8...")

this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

As per @Topaco changing

```
const sharedKeyArray = base64ToArrayBuffer("FJm8qRF66ST7D/ft2lf7Mxi4Rec4oJr6l8fblM0MTLE=");
```

to

```
const sharedKeyArray = new TextEncoder().encode("FJm8qRF66ST7D/ft2lf7Mxi4Rec4oJr6l8fblM0MTLE=")
```

fixed the issue